# Nested API call In function - React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, promise

I have the following JSON Response. It's in an array format

```
[{
created: "2017-11-04T18:48:46.250Z"
gender: "Male"
id: 1
image: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg"
location: {name: "Citadel of Ricks", url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"}
name: "Rick Sanchez"
origin: {name: "Earth (C-137)", url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1"}
species: "Human"
status: "Alive"
type: ""
url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1"
}]
```

The Above API response I am getting from this API URL: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character'. Now I also need origin dimensions and locations dimension data which we can get from that URL from the origin and location object. like below. For each items I will need that origin and location details

````
location: {name: "Citadel of Ricks", url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"}
origin: {name: "Earth (C-137)", url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1"}```

How can I get a response like below format :
````

name,
Image
gender,
origin name,
origin-Dimension,
location name,
location dimension

I have tried the following function, but have not gotten the desired result. as It returns origin details, how can I get the location details as well?

```
    return axios.get(`${url}`)
      .then(response => {
        const data = response.data.results;
        const promises = data.map((item: { origin: { url: string; }; }) => {
          if (item.origin.url) {
            return axios.get(item?.origin?.url)
              .then(response => response.data);
          }
        });
        return Promise.all(promises).then(originResponse => {
          const result = data.map((item: any, index: any) => {
            return {
              ...item,
              originResponse: originResponse[index]
            };
          });
          return result;
        });
      });
  };
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you're asking us how to use that specific API, surely the vendor provides documentation?  What have you tired and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I have tried to call a function which returns api response. but how to manage nested API call with all items of array?

Comment: Making an API call doesn't change just because the target URL came from an array.  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.

Comment: @David I have updated the question. Please check and help me if you can

Answer (score 0):

> It returns origin details

That is expected, because you're using the "origin" URL:

```
const promises = data.map((item: { origin: { url: string; }; }) => {
  if (item.origin.url) {                // <-- look here
    return axios.get(item?.origin?.url) // <-- and here
      .then(response => response.data);
  }
});
```

> how can I get the location details as well?

If making a request to one URL works, and you want to make a request to another URL, one approach you can try is to make a request to that other URL.  For example, consider this:

```
const originPromises = data.map((item: { origin: { url: string; }; }) => {
  if (item.origin.url) {                // <-- look here
    return axios.get(item?.origin?.url) // <-- and here
      .then(response => response.data);
  }
});

const locationPromises = data.map((item: { location: { url: string; }; }) => {
  if (item.location.url) {                // <-- look here
    return axios.get(item?.location?.url) // <-- and here
      .then(response => response.data);
  }
});
```

Notice what I've done here.  Where the API request to the "origin" URL has been onserved to work as expected, I used the exact same process for the "location" URL.

The next step is for you to decide and implement what you want to *do* with this data.  You're returning the results, so presumably this is being invoked in a function somewhere.  If that functions returns "origins" then you can put the new code in a function which returns "locations".  If the "origin" and "location" need to be combined, you can write logic to combine them in this function after they've all been fetched, associating them with each other into whatever data structure makes sense for your data.

But overall the point is that you're getting the "origin" data because you're requesting the "origin" data.  If you also want to get the "location" data then what you'd do is also request the "location" data.

---

**Edit:** As requested in comments below, here's an example of how to separately await the two arrays of promises using `await`:

```
const originResults = await Promise.all(originPromises);
const locationResults = await Promise.all(locationPromises);
```

At this point `originResults` is the array of "origins" from the API and `locationResults` is the array of "locations" from the API.  You can loop over those arrays, map them to a different structure, combine them into one resulting array using whatever logic you wish, etc.

Comment: And how can combine that locationPromises response in Promise.all() that's my main question. @David

Comment: @SurbhiDavara: How do you *want* to "combine" them?  I don't know your data.  I don't know what this function is intended to return.  If you just want to return whatever data in whatever format then you can use `Promise.all([...originPromises, ...locationPromises])`  But that would result in an array that's a mix of "origins" and "locations".  Alternatively you could separate these into two different functions, one which returns "origins" and one which returns "locations".  Or you could individually await each "origin" and each "location", "combining" as you go.  It's up to your needs.

Comment: I did that Promise.all([...promises, ...locationPromises]), but I will need the origin and location response separately

Comment: @SurbhiDavara: If you make your function `async` then you can `await` them separately very easily: `const originResults = await Promise.all(originPromises);  const locationResults = await Promise.all(locationPromises);`  Failing the use of `async` and `await`, you'd probably have to nest one callback inside the other, which is ugly but not impossible.

Comment: So, which is the proper way to get the response which am I required?

Comment: @SurbhiDavara: "The proper way" is whatever you're trying to achieve.  Personally I prefer the async/await syntax.  Make whatever function holds this code an `async` function and then `await` the two calls to `Promise.all`, then you'll have your two separate arrays of results.

Comment: Okay, Can you write that code? Because I did but got both responses together. I want that it should be separated by key

Comment: @SurbhiDavara: I've updated the answer to include an example of how to use the `await` keyword with `Promise.all`.